# Optimizing run time when using R functions with if-options

Tags: r, function

I aim to optimize the run time procedure of my R function.
More specifically, my R function contains various if-options and when running, for instance, a simulation using the function, I need to fix the function option.
Is there any possibility to make R to use the function without always checking each if-option, i.e. skipping all other options and directly jumping to the prespecified one?
Below there is an example with two functions: `fun1()` without any if/else option and `fun2()` with options. Two loops using both functions, effectuating the same computation, then evaluate the run time.

```
# Data
x = rexp(100)

fun1 = function(x){
  
  v= sqrt(x)

  return(v)
}

fun2 = function(x, type = c("a", "b", "c","d","e","f")){
    if(type == "a"){ v = mean(x) }
    if(type == "b"){ v= median(x)}
    if(type == "c"){ v= var(x)}
    if(type == "d"){ v= sd(x)}
    if(type == "e"){ v= sqrt(x)} # type == "e" does the same as fun1
    if(type == "f"){ v= sum(x)}
  return(v)
}

# No. of iterations for loops below
iter = 10000000

system.time(
  for(i in 1:iter){
    res = fun1(x)
  }
)

# user     system      elapsed 
# 19.42      0.06       19.72 

system.time(
for(i in 1:iter){
  res = fun2(x, type = "e")
}
)

# user     system      elapsed 
# 33.10        0.05      33.56
```

Here, the first (useless) loop is much faster compared to the second loop as the function does not need to check always inner options.
So my question is, whether there is any possibility to use `fun2()` while reaching the same run time as obtained using `fun1()`. Does `tryCatch()` help in such a case?

Comment: How about 

```
fun3 = function(x, type = c("a", "b", "c","d","e","f")){
  if(type == "e"){ v= sqrt(x)} # type == "e" does the same as fun1
  else {
    if(type == "a"){ v = mean(x) }
    if(type == "b"){ v= median(x)}
    if(type == "c"){ v= var(x)}
    if(type == "d"){ v= sd(x)}
    if(type == "f"){ v= sum(x)}
  }
  return(v)
}
```

I think this is nearly as fast as fun 1, Nearly as useful as fun2.

Comment: Thanks for that idea! Sure that would nearly be fun1. However, it would only fit if type == "e" was used. So the flexibility of the function is not maintained, which is a drawback for my purpose..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By running a calculation on 100 numbers 10M times, it looks like your benchmarking is mostly measuring "translation speed from R to low-level code" speed rather than underlying calculation time, so it might be measuring the wrong thing.

In many cases, the best performance in R comes from translating your question into a vectorized form, e.g. using nested ifelse (or my preference, `dplyr::case_when`). (Here's my favorite explanation of [vectorization in R](https://www.noamross.net/archives/2014-04-16-vectorization-in-r-why/).)

In your example, `fun1` is faster to translate (not surprisingly), but if you're running a vectorized calculation on a longer data set, the performance quickly becomes very similar to `fun2`, and is basically identical for n = 100k or more. You can see that both functions are inefficient for small batches, since most of the time is taken in translation vs. calculation.

For more suggestions, check this out: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Profiling.html

```
library(tidyverse)
library(microbenchmark)
run_ranges <- function(n) {
  x = rexp(n)
  summary(microbenchmark(fun1(x), fun2(x, "e"), unit = "ns", times = 1000))
}
ranges <- 10 ^ c(1:6)
sum_table <- tibble(ranges = rep(ranges, each = 2)) %>%
  bind_cols(results = map_dfr(ranges, run_ranges))
ggplot(sum_table, aes(x = ranges, y = mean/ranges, color = expr)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_log10(name = "#s per run", labels = scales::comma) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "ns per calculation", labels = scales::comma)
```

[image]